# Clarity on FFmpeg Filter graph description

Tags: ffmpeg, libav

I'm using libavfilter C API to scale my video.

I started to read the documents related to libavfilter and got stuck at [Filtergraph-description](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtergraph-description).

I don't understand the terminology "filter pads". Throughout the documents, I came across these terms like filter input pad and the output pad.

It would be really appreciable if anyone explains the filter pads in a simple way. Also please share any documents or links related to libavfilter C API examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**pad** (pæd)
*The fleshy cushion-like underpart of the foot of a cat, dog, etc*

---

I never liked the term "pad" when used in the context of filtering and I don't know why that term was used. Replacing it with the word "node" may make it more comprehendible.

This can be visually represented with the `graph2dot` tool:

[image]

In this example the split filter makes two identical copies of a video. One copy is flipped, and then the hstack filter stacks them side-by-side to create the output.

Each filter is linked, and each link is connected to an input "node" (pad) and an output "node" (pad).

This may make more sense if you've ever used software that uses [node graph architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node_graph_architecture) such as Nuke or the unfortunately discontinued Apple Shake.

A filter with no input pads is called a "source", and a filter with no output pads is called a "sink". Source filter examples include [testsrc2](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#allrgb_002c-allyuv_002c-color_002c-haldclutsrc_002c-nullsrc_002c-pal75bars_002c-pal100bars_002c-rgbtestsrc_002c-smptebars_002c-smptehdbars_002c-testsrc_002c-testsrc2_002c-yuvtestsrc), [color](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#allrgb_002c-allyuv_002c-color_002c-haldclutsrc_002c-nullsrc_002c-pal75bars_002c-pal100bars_002c-rgbtestsrc_002c-smptebars_002c-smptehdbars_002c-testsrc_002c-testsrc2_002c-yuvtestsrc), and [sine](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#sine). These filters can generate video or audio by themselves with no input needed, so there are no input pads. Example to output a video test pattern, 3 seconds, 1280x720:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc2=d=3:s=1280x720 output.mp4
```

A sink is less useful for most users. One use is to test complicated filtergraphs. If you have a filterchain that you want to temporarily omit then you can terminate it into a sink, such as [anullsink](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#anullsink). There is no output from a sink. It's kind of like using `/dev/null` if you're familiar with that.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. If I imagine the ffmpeg filters as a physical electronic device which has multiple input and output ports attached to it to receive and send signals. These ports are considered as in/out pads of filters and assuming ffmpeg filter links as physical wires with connectors on both ends to connect filters. These connectors are considered as in/out pads of filter links.

Comment: A filter with no input pads is called a "source", and a filter with no output pads is called a "sink".

@llogan Could you please help me to understand this line. How it's possible that source filter with no input pad? if there is no input pad, then where it receives input for the filter chain and also sink filter should have an output pad to take filtered data out.

Comment: @Vencat Updated answer.

Comment: I think that the name came from PCB contact pads.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_pad